# loading ggplot2 (colorspace, actually) opens up x11

Tags: r, ggplot2, x11, color-space

Whenever I so much as *load* `ggplot2`, X11 jumps into action (hogging resources).

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Is what I do, and boom – X11

The thing is, I don't want to use X11, nor do I want it to be open – I want to use Quartz and the build-in graphics in RStudio.

Whenever I close X11, so goes my R session.

My setup:

- OS X Yosemite 10.10.2
- R 3.1.2
- Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
- ggplot 1.0.0
- XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2)
- OS X also recently (yesterday?) updated the Command Line Tools to 6.2

This problem occurs:

- In RStudio
- using a ST3 REPL package
- the R console

How did I mess this up, and how I can I stop this madness?

**Update**: Turns out (see comments), the package [colorspace](http://cran.r-project.org/package=colorspace) in version 1.2-5 is at fault, not ggplot2.

**Update**: The problem seems to be solved as of colorspace version 1.2-6.

Comment: Isn't X11 and Xquartz the same thing in Yosemite ? I also have the X11 app on Yosemite but when I click on about X11, I get `XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2)`. I have just realized that ggplot2 does the same thing on my computer. I hadn't noticed it before so I suppose it appeared after today's upgrade (ggplot2 complained about missing tcltk.dylib file and had to reinstall Xquartz.

Comment: You mention RStudio but do not say whether this is happening inside Rstudio. You also provide nothing about which of the Mac builds are being used. (I'm not sure but I think it's possible to using the SL build in Yosemite). It doesn't happen to me using on a Yosemite machine wtih the MacGUI with R 3.1.2 Patched nor does it happen when I close that session and open an RStudio session. I suspect you did something in RStudio but cannot find a "switch" that looks to be responsible. (I do have XQuartz  installed.)

Comment: Can confirm this happening to me as well. It is not necessary RStudio- just open a terminal and run R, then loading ggplot2 will trigger this feature. If you close X11 then R crashes. It did not happen a few weeks ago and neither R or ggplot2 have been updated since, which makes this very weird indeed. I have not tested in a system without X11 installed, but it is happening in two different Mac computers.

Comment: @ddiez. Without X11 installed, ggplot2 complains about missing tcltk.dylib library. I had to reinstall Xquartz yesterday to load ggplot2.

Comment: @BondedDust I added more platform information, let me know if anything more would be helpful.
I don't recall changing any settings that might account for this.
The problem also exists in the R Console, so it's not an RStudio thing.

Comment: There have been some changes with Mac/Tcltk/X11 in 3.1.2: http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/NEWS.html so I think you should probably take this to the R-dev mailing list.

Comment: @Spacedman I see. I just added an issue to the [ggplot2 github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1064) site in case- but may be it is not ggplot2's fault.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks – it's weird though that this problem arose only *yesterday*, with 3.1.2 out for several months now ...
Makes me think it might be something with ggplot or X11 update instead.

Comment: Sorry I meant 3.1.3, out yesterday!

Comment: According to the response [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1064#issuecomment-78037220) this is caused by the package `colorspace`, and should be fixed in time.

Comment: If you need immediate fix, would try reverting to `colorspace 1.2-4` which is what I am running and am not having problems with a system that otherwise appears very similar to yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and the [github issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1064) in the ggplot2 page, this is cause by the package `colorspace` version "1.2-5". You can wait to a new version of the package with a fix. Or, a temporary solution is to install a previous version of `colorspace`. If you have the `devtools` package installed you can easily do:

```
library(devtools)
install_version("colorspace", "1.2-4")
```

Comment: in the meantime, version "1.2-6" has been released which solves the problem, too.