# ggplot2 sourcing error: X11 library is missing

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, installation

I'm trying to load ggplot2 library for R.

1) I've installed ggplot2 by this command. It was installed with no errors

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
```

2) Then i'm trying to use

```
library(ggplot2)
```

and get an error

> Error : .onLoad не удалось в loadNamespace() для 'tcltk', подробности:
>   вызов: fun(libname, pkgname)   ошибка: X11 library is missing: install
>   XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org Ошибка: не удалась загрузка пакета
>   или пространства имен для ‘ggplot2’

3) Now i try to install XQuartz library by

```
install.packages("XQuartz")
```

and get this

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘XQuartz’ is not available
>   (for R version 3.1.2)

My R version 3.1.2
OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Can you help me in installing ggplot2 pls?

Comment: [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) is not an R package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading ggplot2 opens up x11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952128/loading-ggplot2-opens-up-x11)

Comment: @shadow - This doesn't look like a duplicate of that to me.  Something not loading at all is different than it loading when you don't want it to...

Comment: Thanks @Dason. I guess I jumped to conclusions there. Just saw the other post earlier today and figured that the problem was caused by the same thing. Apparently not. Obviously retracted my close vote.

Comment: Refer to the answer in the link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952128/loading-ggplot2-colorspace-actually-opens-up-x11

Answer (score 10):

The OS update deleted the /usr/X11 and /usr/X11R6 symlinks. I had to just re-install XQuartz from [macosforge](http://xquartz.macosforge.org) which will setup the symlinks again.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error message about the missing library.

Nowadays, a lot of libraries can be installed with Homebrew. For this instance it would be:

```
brew cask install xquartz
```

Newer users of Homebrew may need this command:

```
brew install --cask xquartz
```

Comment: It seems as if the homebrew syntax changed and now the command is "brew install --cask xquartz"

Comment: Thanks @Phil I just updated my answer to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

R opens graphics windows using the standard X11 library on Macs, which is no longer part of the standard MacOS. When you try running programs that open a graphics window, you will get a message: "Error in check_for_XQuartz(): X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org" and it should work