# How to knit a project while there is an error message for a missing library

Tags: r

I encountered issue to knit a project due to an error message like below:

```
Error in check_for_XQuartz() : 
  X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> View -> check_for_XQuartz
Execution halted
```

However, I was only uploading a csv file at that line. I am very confused. How do you skip this error message and produce(knit) a html? Please advice. Thank you.

SH.

Comment: This looks like a system package (not an R package) is missing from your computer that is required to make plots with packages like ggplot2. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984243/ggplot2-sourcing-error-x11-library-is-missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 sourcing error: X11 library is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984243/ggplot2-sourcing-error-x11-library-is-missing)