# R Markdown: File imports in chunk but not in knit

Tags: r, import, markdown

I'm working on an R Markdown that imports a file using the code:

```
BaseData <- read_excel("~/Desktop/Marlin Thomas/Russia/BaseData.xlsx")
```

When I execute the above as part of a chunk, the file imports.
If I highlight and run the code, the file imports.
When I execute knit on the markdown, there is an error message
No such file or directory.
The consoles reports that X11 library is missing.
Attempts to import other files from the same directory during knit work fine. I've tried renaming the file and saving it as css and using `read_csv()`.
I've run the above commands in another markdown with the same results.
What am I not understanding about knit or about this file name?

I tried importing it via another markdown.
Renaming the file.
Saving it as a csv file.
The file does not import in a knit but imports when a chunk is executed.

Comment: Possibly related to your X11 library issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984243/ggplot2-sourcing-error-x11-library-is-missing. As for your other issue, get the RMarkdown to print what it thinks `getwd()` is and see if it conforms to your expectations.

Comment: I was able to get the import to work by using the full name and not ~. What puzzles me is that HDI<- read_excel("~/Downloads/HDR21-22_Statistical_Annex_HDI_Table.xlsx") in the same chunk imports without a problem. I would really like to understand why there its a difference.