# XQuartz opens automatically when RStudio opens

Tags: rstudio

Lately, whenever I launch RStudio, the XQuartz app also automatically launches.  How can I stop this from happening? (It's annoying!)

The only thing I could find related to this issue was this stackoverflow question: [loading ggplot2 (colorspace, actually) opens up x11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952128/loading-ggplot2-colorspace-actually-opens-up-x11). (I do have the `colorspace` package installed [v. 1.3-2] but for me XQuartz starts up immediately upon starting RStudio, not after a particular library is loaded.)

This behavior started very recently, possibly corresponding to the installation of the package `sqldf`, which does appear to force-open the XQuartz app when it's loaded, although I don't know how it could be causing XQuartz to open before the library is even loaded into the current session.  I also tried deleting the `.RData` and `.Rhistory` files in my working directory and restarting RStudio, but it didn't help.

Version and system information:

`RStudio Version 1.1.453`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0
```

Comment: In case anyone is also looking for a possible solution, here is what I did: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/308#issuecomment-618038573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP here. Seems like the issue I was having stopped on its own.  Updating to RStudio version 1.1.456 and/or R version 3.5.1 may have helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is still happening to me on OS X with RStudio `1.4.1103`, R `4.0.2`, `sqldf v0.4-11` and `gsubfn v0.7`.   It happens immediately upon loading `sqldf` (which has `gsubfn` as a dependency).

Based on a hint from this [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/hrbrmstr/status/1052221734705860608), I figured out that if I run this line before loading `sqldf`, I can bypass loading the loading of XQuartz:

`options(gsubfn.engine = "R") # This stops the loading of XQuartz on Mac`

Answer (score 0):

Including `options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)` in my .Rprofile solved the problem for me. The quote below from the [rgl vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/rgl.html) explains why it suggests this:

> Default display

> There are two ways in which rgl scenes are normally displayed within R. The older one is in a dedicated window. In Unix-alikes this is an X11 window; it is a native window in Microsoft Windows. On macOS, the XQuartz system (see https://www.xquartz.org) needs to be installed to support this.

> To suppress this display, set options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE) before opening a new rgl window. See the help page for the rgl.useNULL function for how to set this before starting R.

> The newer way to display a scene is by using WebGL in a browser window or in the Viewer pane in RStudio. To select this, set options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE). Each operation that would change the scene will return a value which triggers a new WebGL display when printed.

Answer (score -1):

1. Launch RStudio
2. Invoke Global Options (`Menu Tools → Global Options…` or press `cmd-comma` keys)
3. If not already done, in the left pane select `General`
4. Tab `Advanced`
5. Under section **OS Integration**
6. In `Rendering engine:` select `Desktop OpenGL`
7. Click on `Apply`
8. Restart RStudio

---

System used:

- macOS Ventura 13.2.1 (Intel)
- RStudio version 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353)
- R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31) -- "Innocent and Trusting"

Comment: This did not work for me.

macOS Ventura 13.5.1 (M1)

RStudio Version 2023.06.1+524 (2023.06.1+524)

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) -- "Beagle Scouts"